# Unrecognized instance if the flower garden

Tags: parasites

There is a strange instance that appeared in my flower garden overnight. Does anyone have an idea what it is?

Thanks,

Aliaksei

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: In the first picture I see what appears to be some bindweed. I'd get rid of that if I were you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to be a slime mold. It won't hurt any of the plants (it's feeding on the mulch).

Comment: I can confirm that it is slime mold. You may find [more information on slime mold](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/fungus-lichen/what-is-slime-mold-slime.htm) and how (not) to get rid of it.